# Background color and scroll issue.

Tags: css, background, css-animations

I need some help here. My final project is due tomorrow and the mobile responsive view of the app is completely off. I don't know how else to explain it other than just giving you the link to the URL.

https://venpresath.github.io/FinalProject/#!/home

It appears that the animation that I put onto the spinning record is making the width of the screen larger than the background is.

I tried overflow: Hidden; but it didn't correct the issue.

Comment: This might be difficult to re-create via SO snippets, but I would strongly recommend creating a JSFiddle or Codepen that recreates at least the CSS animation - otherwise once your page is changed, the question becomes useless to future SO users searching for a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work around is to hide the overflow of the record, something like:

```
.homeContent{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `overflow: hidden;` directly on the body tag, this should ensure that whatever happens in the content the body shouldn't scroll horizontally.

Comment: I had given that a shot, but it's not making any difference to the layout :/

Comment: this works for me (in chrome) if I add it via the dev tools inspector. If you can create a fiddle or codepen I can replicate.

Comment: I'm using AngularJS so I have a bunch of JS pages. I'll see if there's another site I can use that I can implement multiple pages with. 

Which area are you adding the overflow: hidden to?

Comment: On the `<body` tag directly. Your problem is nothing to do with angular, you could just recreate the html and css.

Answer (score 0):

you can use transform scale and transform origin css. please add below css. this is the demo http://recordit.co/UK63B2vKiR

```
.homeContent{transform: scale(.8, .8);}
body{background: darkslateblue!Important; overflow-x: hidden;}
*{max-width:100vw;}
```

Comment: @media(max-width:767px){
 .homeContent {transform: scale(.8, .8);}
 body {background: darkslateblue!Important;overflow-x: hidden;}
 *{max-width: 100vw;}
}

Comment: ... Second thought, I just tried this again and it's making the record turn into an egg shape :/

Comment: you must apply the equal scale values for both width and height ratio like **scale(.8, .8)**